# Difficulty in understanding why the Cartesian product of two circles is equivalent to a torus?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I recently learned that the Cartesian product of two circles is topologically equivalent to a torus, and I have some difficult times in understanding this statement.
Here comes a few of my confusions.

1. Suppose we are taking the Cartesian product of $\{(x_1,y_1):x_1^2+y_1^2=r_1^2\}$ and $\{(x_2,y_2):x_2^2+y_2^2=r_2^2\},$ do we get a torus? I understand the explicit and parametric formulas for torus, could we mathematically prove that the Cartesian product of the two circles and the torus are equivalent?
2. After taking Cartesian product of the two circles, we get a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^4,$ but isn't a torus an object in $\mathbb{R}^3?$ How could these two be equivalent?

I have learnt metric space, but don't have much background knowledge in topology. Hope this is something that I could understand. Many thanks for any help and references in advance!

Comment: The typical torus you're probably thinking of (a donut shaped object, without any filling) and $S^1\times S^1$ are NOT the same set of points. As you pointed out, one lives in $\Bbb{R}^3$, the other in $\Bbb{R}^4$ (or just abstractly, depending on how you choose to define $S^1$). However, these two spaces, when equipped with the natural topologies, are *homeomorphic* (an isomorphism in the sense of topological spaces). It is in this sense, that they are 'equivalent' descriptions of what we call a 'torus'.

Comment: Even if you didn't learn about topological spaces, that's fine, since you say you know about metric spaces. The point is that there is a mapping $f:\text{donut in $\Bbb{R}^3$}\to S^1\times S^1$ which is bijective, and such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous (use the induced metric from $\Bbb{R}^3$ on the donut, and the induced metric from $\Bbb{R}^4$ on $S^1\times S^1$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see! I think I understand the homeomorphism now. I was thinking that the Cartesian product of two circles and the torus are exactly the same set of points, but now I understand it wasn't the case. Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2898375/25554 might be helpful

Comment: "I understand the explicit and parametric formulas for torus". You should write it down in your question.

Comment: You have to tell us which "model" of a torus in $\mathbb R^3$ you have in mind. If you do not make this explicit, nobody can write down a homeomorphism.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3161531